# Vuforia Object Recognition Unity Sample results in Android Black Screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing using Unity5.3.5f1 (64 Bit) and have a problem with a black screen on my Nexus 7 Android version 4.4.3 every time I try to launch the app.

I try to implement the Vuforia Object Recognition Unity Sample (https://developer.vuforia.com/library//articles/Training/Vuforia-Object-Recognition-Unity-Sample-Guide) so it should work while I followed the instructions.

I didn't modify the code, just followed the instructions to add the 3D target.

I followed the hints of the developer forum to set the player settings for building https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/issues-and-bugs/camera-not-working-when-app-installed-mobile but nothing changed the situation:

- Setting Rendering Path to "Legacy Deffer"
- changing the Minimum API Level to Android 4.2
- enable "GPU skinning"
- set graphics APIs to "OpenGLES2"

Comment: Did you include your license key for vuforia?

Comment: Yes i did. After i dertermined the Nexus having problems accessing the camera using other applications too i restarted the tablet and that solves the problem. Should have tried this earlier....

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed a lot of problems between unity and mobile devices when building. **There seems to be some residual meta data left on the device from unity so not all changes end up working properly** (which holds the information of what objects the script is attached to). I had an instance where I deleted EVERYTHING in my scene and I had a debug script attached to some of those items that would output some text to the Xcode console in the scripts start() method. After cleaning out the entire scene and redeploying that debug script was sill outputting to the console. I deleted the .meta file associated with that script and redeployed. This deletion stopped the file from running. I have noticed that restarting the device can also fix this issue. Also deleting the meta, deploying, then undoing the delete and running again also fixes some of these issues. You will NOT notice this problem when developing in unity and breakpoints will never be hit, but it will still happen on the mobile device and even run scripts that you completely disabled.